# Reading the position coordinates of nodes/cells/points from VTK files

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I want to read the spacial coordinates of points from a VTK file ( Unstructured grid - XML format).
I'm using python (V 2.7), here is a small version of the code which I'm using.

```
import vtk
import numpy
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName( "MyFile.vtu" )
reader.Update()
field_array = reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray( "MyField" )
# this part will give the values of the "Field" in all points as an array

Point_cordinates = reader.GetOutput().GetPoints.GetData()
# this is not working
```

What I want is to have the X, Y, Z coordinates of all the points listed as an array.
I looked in the documentation and could not find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points:

- parenthesis are missing in last line. Should be

`Point_cordinates = reader.GetOutput().GetPoints().GetData()`

- then you should use vtk_to_numpy :

`numpy_coordinates = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(Point_cordinates)`

See code here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/master/Wrapping/Python/vtkmodules/util/numpy_support.py

And similar post on VTK forum: https://discourse.vtk.org/t/how-to-print-a-list-of-vertices-location-and-ids-using-python/965

Answer (score 0):

So I found this third party tool called `meshio` which can be used for this purpose

you can install this by

`pip install meshio --user`

we can use this as follows

```
import meshio
point_cordinates = meshio.read("YourFileName").points
# this will return a Nx3 array of xyz cordinates
```

ps: I'm still looking for a way to do this with the default vVTK library.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of how to receive the coordinates as a tuple depending on an integer (i.e., the Point ID):

**Example:**

```py
    Point_coordinates = reader.GetOutput().GetPoints().GetData().GetTuple(int)
```